# Confused with passing lambda function as trailing parameter in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, lambda, parameter-passing

Please explain why these errors happened. Thanks

1.

```
fun calculate(a: Int, b: Int, operation: (Int, Int) -> Int): Int {
    return operation(a, b)
}

fun main() {
    val resultAdd1 = calculate(5, 3) { x, y -> x + y }  // this worked
    println("Result of addition: $resultAdd1")

    val resultAdd2 = calculate(5, 3) { (x, y) -> x + y }  // Type mismatch: inferred type is (Int) -> Int but (Int, Int) -> Int was expected
    println("Result of subtraction: $resultAdd2")
}
```

is code inside {} a function? if that so, does calculate(5, 3) { x, y -> x + y } mean passing function inside function?

2.

```
fun greet(action: () -> Unit) {
    println("Preparing to greet...")
    action()
}

fun main() {
    greet {
        println("Hello, World!")  // this worked
    }

    greet {
        () -> println("Hello, World!")  // Type mismatch: inferred type is (Any?) -> Unit but () -> Unit was expected
    }

}
```

Comment: I recommend reading about [higher-order functions and lambdas](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html)  and  [destructuring declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/destructuring-declarations.html).

Answer (score 0):

1. Because `(x, y)` is a part of syntax for [destructuring](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/destructuring-declarations.html). But if you try to change

```
    fun calculate(a: Int, b: Int, operation: (Int, Int) -> Int)
```

to

```
    fun calculate(a: Int, b: Int, operation: (Int) -> Int)
```

it also won't work, even though compiler says that it looks like this. Because it's still incomplete syntax for destructuring.

2. If you decompile your code you will see that in this case Kotlin puts `Function0` instead of your lambda: (to do this click `Tools` -> `Kotlin` -> `Show Kotlin Bytecode` -> `Decompile`)

```
   public static final void greet(@NotNull Function0 action) {
      Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter(action, "action");
      String var1 = "Preparing to greet...";
      System.out.println(var1);
      action.invoke();
   }

   public static final void main() {
      greet((Function0)null.INSTANCE);
   }

   // $FF: synthetic method
   public static void main(String[] var0) {
      main();
   }
```

`Function0` is a functional interface that takes 0 arguments and returns some value.

If you decompile your previous example (1) you will see `Function2` because it takes 2 arguments and returns something:

```
   public static final int calculate(int a, int b, @NotNull Function2 operation) {
      Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter(operation, "operation");
      return ((Number)operation.invoke(a, b)).intValue();
   }

   public static final void main() {
      int resultAdd1 = calculate(5, 3, (Function2)null.INSTANCE);
      String var1 = "Result of addition: " + resultAdd1;
      System.out.println(var1);
   }

   // $FF: synthetic method
   public static void main(String[] var0) {
      main();
   }
```